# Google Code Search-like source code indexer and visualizer

Tags: language-agnostic, search, indexer, code-search-engine

I'm looking for a way to search through our subversion repository or just packaged source code.

Are there any **downloadable** servers/tools like [Google Code Search](http://google.com/codesearch) to index source code (preferable with support of version control systems like svn) and allow us to search in it?

Is there any tool that will index documents too?

Comment: By documents.. are those text based or some binary format or something else?

Comment: I think MSWord and PDF formats are the most common ones.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[FishEye](http://www.atlassian.com/software/fisheye/) or [OpenGrok](http://opengrok.github.io/OpenGrok/) possibly.

There are many tools that will index documents.

Comment: These are good. But is there a system like this that will index both code and documents from svn? Or should I use two systems: one for code and another for documents?
Does OpenGrok index old revisions too?

Answer (score 5):

Google made their internal Kythe source code analyser toolset available on GitHub, see http://www.kythe.io/.

It does a lot more than a simple text-level indexer. At the core it builds an AST graph from the source code and provide tools that operate on it and query it.

Answer (score 4):

I believe the source code for Google Search is available here. It's implemented in Go
https://code.google.com/p/codesearch/

Answer (score 2):

I use [glimpse](http://webglimpse.net/download.php) for code search.  I use the free command line tool, and not the paid web interface.  It's very quick, and can be combined with other tools to quickly find what your looking for.  I find it's easy to setup multiple repositories for different branches of the code. Additionally, I've created a few [scripts to help query, format, and colorize](https://www.theeggeadventure.com/wikimedia/index.php/Colorize_Glimpse) the results.

Answer (score 1):

A language-sensitive source code search engine can be found
at [SD Source Code Search Engine](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/SearchEngine).   It can handle many languages at the same time.
Searches can be performed for patterns in a specific langauge,
or patterns across languages (such as "find identifiers involving TAX").
By being sensitive to langauge tokens, the number of false positives is reduced,
saving time for the user.  It understands C, C++, C#, COBOL, Java, ECMAScript, Java, XML, Verilog, VHDL, and a number of other languages.
[I'm a principal at the company]

Answer (score 1):

[Hound](https://github.com/etsy/Hound) - code search tool with Web UI